# How to get a midi keyboard working in 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, sound, keyboard, midi, lmms

I try to get my midi keyboard running with lmms.

The device ( a yamaha psx e223 connected via a midi-mate 2 ) is listed when i run:

```
amidi -l
IO  hw:1,0,0  USB Device 0x2573:0x10c2 MIDI 1
IO  hw:1,0,1  USB Device 0x2573:0x10c2 MIDI 2
```

When i type **lsusb** its not listed.

Inside LMMS whenever i configure midi in settings it always jumps back to 'dummy' after i restart LMMS to apply the new settings.

I also tryed to setup JACK but always get these errors when trying to 
start it:

```
Mon Feb 10 22:16:34 2014: ERROR: control open "/dev/audio" (No such file or directory)
Mon Feb 10 22:16:34 2014: ERROR: cannot register object path "/org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0": A handler is already registered for /org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0
Mon Feb 10 22:16:34 2014: ERROR: Failed to acquire device name : Audio0 error : A handler is already registered for /org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0
Mon Feb 10 22:16:34 2014: ERROR: Audio device hw:0 cannot be acquired...
Mon Feb 10 22:16:34 2014: ERROR: Cannot initialize driver
Mon Feb 10 22:16:34 2014: ERROR: JackServer::Open failed with -1
Mon Feb 10 22:16:34 2014: ERROR: Failed to open server
```

Edit.: In **aseqdump** no events show up

Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: Do you get some data with `aseqdump`?

Comment: unfortunaly not

Comment: Are you on 13.10 or 13.04? The question says 13.04, but the tag says 13.10.

Comment: How exactly have you connected the PSR to the MIDI Mate? How exactly have you run `aseqdump`?

Comment: i corrected the title. i connected psrs midi out/in to mate's 1/2 midi plugs. I ran aseqdump in Terminal wiith no sudo or params.

Answer (score 0):

try this tutorial 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1303306

i'm thinking you didn't make the connections in JACK and if so that is your problem but the steps on that tutorial should work and the tutorial uses hardware which is VERY similar to yours

** also check your midi connections. remember out on keyboard to in on the midi interface this is a very common problem midi should have been designed with differently shaped plugs on each end but such is life.

Comment: Although the guy in the "tutorial" is using the same keyboard its not of much use. Very little detail on configuration whatsoever just a rough overview of installed packages which aren't even crucial to solve my problem.